# All buttons are missing buttons

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, window-buttons

As you can see that is a picture of my nautilus the home,back,next buttons etc are replaced by a (not found.......... I guess that's what it is)

[image]

Another thing to mention I had installed Gnome3 following this link: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-gnome-38-on-ubuntu/

Then when I rebooted the system there was only a black screen not even the lock screen was loaded. I booted into recovery and uninstalled the apt using root shell.
Since then I am facing thus Trouble.

Comment: You're probably using a theme that isn't compatible. And before yo ask what to do the obvious answer is do not use that theme.

Comment: I tried it with the default theme . It is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved after uninstalling nautilus. I installed Thunar and it works fine. Hope this thread helps anyone in future